# replace Notification actions on click on one of the action button of notification

Tags: android, notifications

I need to give 2 options to user as the notification actions like this.

[image: Two actions]

On clicking on "SNOOZE" button, I need to replace all actions and show 3 other options like this.

[image: Actions after click]

So how could I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove the existing notification on option click and create a new notification with new option.

To clear the notification you can do the following.

```
NotificationManager.cancel(YourNotificationId);
```

You can't dynamically change the visibility of views in notification.

Comment: As far as i know, It is the only way. Without updating the notification itself we can't update it's view.

Comment: I got the solution, Just creating new Notification with same notification Id, but it crashes in below API 21. 
exception: FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification

any idea @nitesh

Comment: please share the code where you are generating the notification

Comment: got the problem, when I'm passing -1 into mBuilder.addAction() as icon, it gives me this.
Any suggestion on this, I don't want action icon